# Finding Unique Elements in a Matrix

Tags: java, hashset

I am working with a 2D array called matrix. I need to retrieve the unique elements in the array.

nil        A        B        C        G        F
y1        a1        b2        c1        g1        f1
y2        a1        b1        c2        g2        f1
y3        a2        b1        c2        g1        f2
y4        a1        b2        c2        g2        f1
y5        a2        b2        c1        g1        f2

So for instance, for column A, I should get a1 and a2. For B, b1 and b2, and so on.

I have tried out different thing, but nothing has worked thus far. Here is what I put together:

```
   public void UniqueElement(String line){

       List tempList = Arrays.asList(line);

       Set set = new HashSet(tempList);
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.printf("%s", set);

   }//UniqueElement Method
```

Here is what I get:

[nil,A,B,C,G,F]
[y1,a1,b2,c1,g1,f1]
[y2,a1,b1,c2,g2,f1]
[y3,a2,b1,c2,g1,f2]
[y4,a1,b2,c2,g2,f1]

Could someone suggest another approach to try to single out unique items in my matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do nested `foreach` loops and walk through the elements in the array. As you go, store "new" or unseen elements in a list. To decide if you've seen an element, walk the list each time and if you get a match, move to the next array element. Otherwise (no match), add the element to the list and move to the next array element.

This algorithm is very brute-force and does not scale well, but it *will* give you a list of the unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare the memory...  Loop over each item and use it as the key to a Map, incrementing the value each time the key is encountered.  Once you are done, loop over the Map and output the keys who's value is 1.

In fact, since you only care about uniqueness, you could use a Boolean as the value. true = unique, false = not unique